# Administrator settings vanished for sheetnode content type nodes

Tags: navigation

I installed the sheetnode module. It was working ok and then the next time I clicked on "Edit" on the node, the following happened:
[image]

I don't know how the links for Publishing options, URL Path settings etc got disabled. I run as an administrator and I edited my permissions too (grant everything under sheetnode module to admin) but to no avail. Please help me get back to those links.

I run drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself. I had my CKEditor module disabled while the "Sheetnode CKEditor" module was enabled. So there was some conflict which led to the disappearance of links.